# How to retrieve My Business reviews from Google

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I'm able to connect to Google My Business and make a call to return the account number, but I can't list the locations associated to the account, and in turn, can't retrieve the reviews.

```
require_once( '/functions/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php' );
require_once( '/functions/mybusiness/MyBusiness.php' );

$client = new Google_Client();

if ( $credentials_file = checkServiceAccountCredentialsFile() ) {
    // set the location manually
    $client->setAuthConfig( $credentials_file );
} elseif ( getenv( 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' ) ) {
    // use the application default credentials
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
} else {
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();

    return;
}

$client->setApplicationName( "Cardall_Orthodontics_Reviews" );
$client->setScopes( [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage' ] );
$service = new Google_Service_Mybusiness( $client );

$accounts     = $service->accounts;
$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
$account      = $accountsList[0];

$locations     = $service->accounts_locations;
$locationsList = $locations->listAccountsLocations( $account->name )->getLocations(); // This is where it's not returning the locations
$location      = $locationsList[0];

$reviews             = $service->accounts_locations_reviews;
$listReviewsResponse = $reviews->listAccountsLocationsReviews( $location->name );
$reviewsList         = $listReviewsResponse->getReviews();
```

When I print $account->name, I can see `accounts/000000000000000000000` (with my account ID) so I'm only assuming it's working up until that point, but I'm not sure why there wouldn't be any locations. I have one added in My Business account.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: Same issue for me too. Keith or @EmilioGort Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I never did find a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You must add to your query required param "readMask":

```
$locationsList = $locations
    ->listAccountsLocations(
        $account->name,
        ['readMask' => ['name', 'title',]]
    )
    ->getLocations();
```

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list